# Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have 3 model: 
1st one:

```
public class CreateFieldModel
{

        public FieldModel fm { get; set; }
        public CategoryModel cm { get; set; }
}
```

2nd one:

```
public class FieldModel
    {
        public string field_Name { get; set; }
        public InputTypeModel itm { get; set; }
        public string input1 { get; set; }
        public string input2 { get; set; }
        public string input3 { get; set; }
        public string input4 { get; set; }

        public List<InputTypeModel> inputs { get; set; }
    }
```

3rd One:

```
 public class InputTypeModel
    {
        public string inputTypeName { get; set; }
        public string inputTypeDesc { get; set; }

    }
```

2 methods:

1st One:

```
public List<InputTypeModel> getInputTypes()
        {
            var inptypes = edu.InputTypes;

            List<InputTypeModel> listInputTypes = new List<InputTypeModel>();
            foreach (var inpType in inptypes)
            {
                listInputTypes.Add(new InputTypeModel { inputTypeName = inpType.Input_Type_Name, inputTypeDesc = inpType.Input_Type_Description });
            }

            return listInputTypes;
        }
```

when this method executes listInputTypes has three different values.. i check it by debugging.. so no roblem here. This methos is under the class FormManagement.. I am calling this method from the following action method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult createNewField(CreateFieldModel cfm, string fcode)
    {
        FormManagement ffm = new FormManagement();
        cfm.fm.inputs = ffm.getInputTypes();
        return View(cfm);

    }
```

when `cfm.fm.inputs = ffm.getInputTypes();` executes it is showing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." message... I am quite beginner to mvc.. please help

Comment: Your cfm is most probably null when you call createNewField. Use a debugger. Set a breakpoint on this line. See your call stack and check that the calling function provides the correct value for cfm.

Comment: yes it is null... how can i solve it??

Comment: Well why did you *expect* it to be non-null?

Comment: ffm.getInputTypes return the exact value i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what you really want to achieve with cfm-parameter in your action, the only thing I can suggest is to check for null references and create new instances before you assign them:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult createNewField(CreateFieldModel cfm, string fcode)
{
    FormManagement ffm = new FormManagement();
    if (cfm == null)
    {
        cfm = new CreateFieldModel();
    }
    if (cfm.fm == null)
    {
        cfm.fm = new FieldModel();
    }
    cfm.fm.inputs = ffm.getInputTypes();
    return View(cfm);
}
```

Of course, this supposes that your not relying on incoming data through your route parameters. If you are, you need to check why the values are not getting passed in, but I'm guessing you don't need it as a parameter in the first place.